# ListView in an Activity in a TabHost

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-tabhost

OK, I've got a quite complex little setup here. My main activity is a `TabHost`, and one of those tabs displays some text, a button, and then a `ListView`. For some reason, the `ListView` will only show 1 item. When I add more items, only the first one in the list shows.

tabmenu.xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
        <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"/>
        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <include layout="@layout/main"/>
            <include layout="@layout/scheduler"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
</ScrollView>
```

Scheduler.xml: (This is where the listview is)

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/schedulerLayout">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop ="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/timeLayout">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/currentHours"
            android:textSize="50dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:text=":"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/currentMinutes"
            android:textSize="50dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ampm"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/currentDayOfWeek"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/currentDate"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scheduleButton"
        android:text="@string/newSchedule"
        android:layout_below="@id/timeLayout"/>
<!--android:enabled="false"-->

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/scheduleButton"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"/>

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/scheduler_list_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <!--                android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"-->
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main.java:

```
//adds tabs to view
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Auto Respond")
        .setIndicator(" Auto Respond ")
        .setContent(R.id.mainLayout);

tabHost.addTab(spec);

spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Scheduler")
        .setIndicator(" Scheduler ")
        .setContent(R.id.schedulerLayout);


tabHost.addTab(spec);
tabHost.getTabWidget();


//start setup of list display
int number = 0;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>();
HashMap<String, Object> row  = new HashMap<String, Object>();

//gets number of items, gets title, startTime, etc. here (lots of code, so I cut it out)

if(curTitle != null && !curTitle.equals(""))
{
    row  = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    row.put("Title", curTitle);
    row.put("Time", time);
    row.put("Day", dayText);
    row.put("Month", monthText);
    data.add(row);
}

//create list
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,
        data,
        R.layout.schedulerow,
        new String[] {"Title","Time","Day", "Month"},
        new int[] { R.id.scheduleListTitle, R.id.scheduleListTime,R.id.scheduleListDays, R.id.scheduleListMonths});

listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Any ideas as to why it only shows the first item in my `ListView`? I tried simply changing `Activity` to `ListActivity` and it FC'd. I don't really want to re-do all of my code to make it work as a `ListActivity`, so I want to keep it as `Activity` if possible.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `data` has more than one item? When you add more items, do you use `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: I have confirmed that `data` and `adapter` both have 2 items. I don't use `notifyDataSetChanged()`. I did try just now though, and it didn't seem to help.

Comment: You are trying to display a lot of information and you have nested your ListView in a ScrollView... Do you have to scroll to see the ListView? If so, the ListView is consuming the gestures preventing the ScrollView from scrolling which in turn prevents you from seeing the entire ListView.

Comment: Good call. That was the problem. I removed the ScrollView and it is displaying fine. If you want to submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to display a lot of information and you have nested your ListView in a ScrollView...  Do you have to scroll to see the ListView?

Nesting two scrollable Views usually doesn't work because, in this case, the ListView consumes the gestures preventing the ScrollView from scrolling which in turn prevents you from seeing the entire ListView.